# 別ファイルからブロック定義を上書きし、画面に反映する方法

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD2019にて、下記のソースで既存のブロック定義を更新し、画面に反映させようとしていますが、UpdateAnonymousBlocks()で「メソッドまたは操作は実装されていません。」とエラーが出てしまいます。
AutoCAD2010では同じソースでエラーなく処理が可能だったのですがやり方が変わったのでしょうか。
また、他の手段による実装をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけると助かります。

```
Dim dwgPath = "ファイルパス"
Dim listItem As SymbolItemClass = DirectCast(SymbolListBox.SelectedItem, SymbolItemClass)
Dim id As ObjectId
Dim dbObj As New BlockTableRecord
Using dbA As Database = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase()
    Try
        Using sourceDb As Database = New Database(False, False)
            sourceDb.ReadDwgFile(dwgPath, System.IO.FileShare.Read, False, Nothing)
            id = dbA.Insert(listItem.Name, sourceDb, False)

            Dim oTr As Transaction = dbA.TransactionManager.StartTransaction
            dbObj = DirectCast(oTr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead), BlockTableRecord)
            dbObj.UpdateAnonymousBlocks()
            oTr.Commit()
            oTr.Dispose()
        End Using
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "VB.NET 例外")
    End Try
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

エラーの内容からそのメソッドの処理が実装されていない感じがします。
一度、開発元に問い合わせてみてはいかがでしょうか。